# Разбить dataframe по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

У меня есть датафрейм, состоящий из двух столбцов. в первос записаны емейлы пользователей,а во втором - страны проживания. Мне нужно выбрать из первого те значения, которе содержат gmail.com или hotmail.com. А потом построить график "отношение количества gmail.com и hotmail.com в соответствии со страной."
В чем ошибка?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv("/home/ann/df(1).csv", sep=';')
gmail_list = []
hotmail_list = []

for i in df[['email', 'country_code']]:
    if "@gmail.com" in i:
      gmail_list.append(df.loc[:,'country_code'])
    elif "@hotmail.com" in i:
      hotmail_list.append(country_code)
```

[график](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-s8SdNMUZA8ruJ1bRpza9idU5GT6-4l0)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы можете привести пример данных или выложить CSV файл?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YYb3twbRxPpy5zJ-wWSp40xMHt6PGMix

Comment: вам нужно показать только два домена? `yahoo.com` и `outlook.com` - на графике быть не должно?

Comment: Да, только эти два домена

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Pandas данную задачу можно решить однострочным (one-liner) выражением:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\df(1).csv', sep=';')

(df.assign(domain=df['email'].str.extract(r'@(.*)', expand=False))
   .query("domain in ['gmail.com','hotmail.com']")
   .groupby(['country_code','domain'])
   .count()['email']
   .unstack('domain', fill_value=0)
   .plot.bar(rot=0, stacked=True))

plt.show()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В процентах:

```
(df.assign(domain=df['email'].str.extract(r'@(.*)', expand=False))  # extract domain from email
   .query("domain in ['gmail.com','hotmail.com']")          # filter domains
   .groupby('country_code')['domain']                       # group by `country_code`
   .value_counts(normalize=True)                            # and count unique values per group (normalize: relative frequency)
   .mul(100)                                                # convert factor to percentage
   .unstack('domain', fill_value=0)                         # pivot: transform long to wide
   .plot.bar(rot=0, stacked=True, figsize=(12,8)))
)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это работает?

Сначала надо вычленить домен из `email`:

```
In [113]: df.assign(domain=df['email'].str.extract(r'@(.*)', expand=False))
Out[113]:
                                     email country_code       domain
0            12345kinglobito94@hotmail.com           RU  hotmail.com
1           12345arturdyikan6211@gmail.com           RU    gmail.com
2    12345leonardosebastianld.20@gmail.com           PE    gmail.com
3             12345k23156876vs@hotmail.com           RU  hotmail.com
4               12345jhuillcag@hotmail.com           PE  hotmail.com
..                                     ...          ...          ...
995               nilton223009@hotmail.com           PE  hotmail.com
996                      xasbkar@gmail.com           RU    gmail.com
997                           kl@gmail.com           RU    gmail.com
998            emerson-carauna@hotmail.com           BR  hotmail.com
999              shamkhalaevamir@gmail.com           RU    gmail.com

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

потом отфильтровать, чтобы остались только `gmail.com` и `hotmail.com`:

```
In [114]: (df.assign(domain=df['email'].str.extract(r'@(.*)', expand=False))
     ...:    .query("domain in ['gmail.com','hotmail.com']"))
     ...:
Out[114]:
                                     email country_code       domain
0            12345kinglobito94@hotmail.com           RU  hotmail.com
1           12345arturdyikan6211@gmail.com           RU    gmail.com
2    12345leonardosebastianld.20@gmail.com           PE    gmail.com
3             12345k23156876vs@hotmail.com           RU  hotmail.com
4               12345jhuillcag@hotmail.com           PE  hotmail.com
..                                     ...          ...          ...
995               nilton223009@hotmail.com           PE  hotmail.com
996                      xasbkar@gmail.com           RU    gmail.com
997                           kl@gmail.com           RU    gmail.com
998            emerson-carauna@hotmail.com           BR  hotmail.com
999              shamkhalaevamir@gmail.com           RU    gmail.com

[954 rows x 3 columns]
```

считаем количество различных доменов для каждой страны:

```
In [115]: (df.assign(domain=df['email'].str.extract(r'@(.*)', expand=False))
     ...:    .query("domain in ['gmail.com','hotmail.com']")
     ...:    .groupby('country_code')['domain']
     ...:    .value_counts(normalize=True)
     ...: )
Out[115]:
country_code  domain
AR            hotmail.com    0.750000
              gmail.com      0.250000
BR            hotmail.com    0.609375
              gmail.com      0.390625
PE            hotmail.com    0.702564
              gmail.com      0.297436
RU            gmail.com      0.956298
              hotmail.com    0.043702
US            gmail.com      0.900000
              hotmail.com    0.100000
Name: domain, dtype: float64
```

делаем `PIVOT`:

```
In [116]: (df.assign(domain=df['email'].str.extract(r'@(.*)', expand=False))
     ...:    .query("domain in ['gmail.com','hotmail.com']")
     ...:    .groupby('country_code')['domain']
     ...:    .value_counts(normalize=True)
     ...:    .mul(100)
     ...:    .unstack('domain', fill_value=0)
     ...: )
Out[116]:
domain        gmail.com  hotmail.com
country_code
AR             25.00000     75.00000
BR             39.06250     60.93750
PE             29.74359     70.25641
RU             95.62982      4.37018
US             90.00000     10.00000
```

рисуем график...

Comment: Большое спасибо! А для графика в  процентном соотношении  количества, что мне нужно  изменить?